# Perform "systemctl edit" with ansible?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible

I recently learned to perform `sudo systemctl edit <SERVICE>` instead of editting the service file under `/lib/systemd/...`

Problem is, I'd like to do this with ansible.

This doesn't seem to be possible with either the systemd module or the service module:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html

Am I missing an option, or will I have to do this manually?

Comment: Why do you want to use an *interactive feature* with ansible? Just replace the `.service` file directly and run `systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: @Panki I have experienced firsthand that an upgrade will replaced the `.service` file in `/lib/systemd/...`. Making the replacement pointless. Only an override.conf file, as generated by `sudo systemctl edit <SERVICE>` isn't ephemeral.

Comment: so just create the override.conf file yourself? it's documented (and doesn't have to be called override.conf)

Comment: the problem is that I want to AUTOMATE the file creations, but again LP showed his short sightednes ;(
and `edit` doesn't have an option "create the empty files" which then would make it easier, but that would be heaven on earth which we can't have

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On systemd `systemctl edit <service>` will create a drop-in directory to `/etc/systemd/system/<service>.service.d`. Here's what I did, an outtake from a role:

```yml
# file module will create a directory if missing
- name: Create <service>.service.d directory
  file:
    path: /etc/systemd/system/<service>.service.d/
    state: directory
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0755

# template module will create a file
- name: Copy <service>.service drop-in
  template:
    src: <service>.service.j2
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/<service>.service.d/override.conf
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  notify: daemon-reload # Don't forget to do `systemctl daemon-reload`!
```

This can be extended with `when` and/or `group_vars` if you have a non-homogenous setup.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It will do that everywhere, it's systemctl functionality, independent of OS. But thanks for the code, I'll accept it as answer so people looking the same thing up can find it.

Comment: I noticed `systemctl edit xxx` on Ubuntu 20 uses `/etc/systemd/system/<service>.service.d/override.conf` (instead of `override.service`). Not sure if it makes a difference, but other than that this approach works for us!